# Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at

Tags: regex, perl, file, debugging

I try to skip all the devices starting by /dev/raw in the file in /proc/partitions file if exists and store others to an array. So I have a block of code like:

```
sub get_proc_partitions {
    my ($self, $device_name) = @_;
    my @partitions;

    open(PART, "/proc/partitions") || die "can't open /proc/partitions: $!";
    while (<PART>) {
        my @field = split;
        # Skip this line if the fourth field starts with 'ram'
        next if $field[3] =~ /^ram/;
        # this regex matches lines like the following.
        # in this example it will capture hdb
        #   3    64   78150744 hdb 157 735 2168 1720 1745 437 17432 
        if (/^\s*(?:\d+\s+){3}(\S+)\s.*/) {
            my $part = $1;
            if ( defined $device_name ) {
                push(@partitions, $part) if ($part =~ /$device_name/);
            } else {
                push(@partitions, $part);
            } 
         }
      }
close(PART);
return \@partitions;
}
```

And this code will return me an error like:

```
 Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at <filename> line 928, <PART> line 2
```

And this line refers to:

```
next if $field[3] =~ /^ram/;
```

Comment: There might be empty lines in the file, then field #4 won't be defined

Comment: If you're on Linux, something like [Linux::Info::DiskStats](https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux::Info::DiskStats) might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check number of fields detected/generated by split or assume default value of the checked field.

```
#  "@field <4" - less than four fields 
next if @field <4 || $field[3] =~ /^ram/;
```

Answer (score 2):

When I issue `cat /proc/partitions` then the 2nd line is empty:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   1        0      65536 ram0
   1        1      65536 ram1
 ...
```

I guess so is yours. Insert a `next unless /\S/;` right after the `while` to skip empty lines:

```
while (<PART>) {
    next unless /\S/;   # skip empty lines
    my @field = split;
    ...
```